# Can NestedScrollview and ConstraintLayout work together?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying the new `ConstraintLayout` and it's really cool and simple.
I tried to apply it in a NestedScrollview inside coordinate layout where `ConstraintLayout` is the parent of the `NestedScrollView`.

But it didn't work, and all views collapsed vertically. How can I solve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:layout_width="411dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="367dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="367dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="76" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Post your design code.

Comment: mmmm, give me 2mn i have deleted the layout. i will remake the view

Comment: posted ! all they come collapsed vertically

Answer (score 3):

I might be late but adding `android:fillViewport="true"`in NestedScrollView should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212141),This has already been fixed in `constraint-layout 1.0.0-alpha2` (available with `Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2`).

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint layout takes the whole space and thus your nested scrollview will not be scrollable. use `wrap_content` for the width instead.

```
...
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" <---here
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
...
```